# If you set crates of different masses to the same initial velocity, which one will stop first and which one will have the greater displacement?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, friction

> If you set two crates of different masses to the same initial velocity, which one will take the longest amount of time to come to a stop? Which one will travel the longest distance? Which one will experience the greatest net force (while stopping)?

I have no idea how to do this. Intuition tells me they would travel the same distance but the heavier mass would take the most time, and the heavier one experiences the greatest force. BUT when I do the calculations, change in momentum equals force times time. And for the heavier object, it will be a greater change in momentum equalling a force times time, and either force or time has to be greater, and I don't know which one. I guess force, because there is more friction for heavier objects? But then that would mean they would travel different distances in the same amount of time. As you can see, I am very lost.